# ESTA overstayed 1 day

Tags: esta

I got stopped at the airport and a man told me I over stayed on my ESTA, I got home and checked the dates...I stayed 90 day in the usa but my flight was overnight so I landed the next day witch would have been the 91st day but my 91st day wasn't in the US, I checked my passport and the records showed I left on the right date, But now I can't get a ESTA again,

Is the 90 days from leaving the USA or landing in your own country ?

Comment: Are you allowing for the fact that both July and August have 31 days?

Comment: The important date is when you leave. When did you arrive, what was the date on the stamp in your passport, and what date did you leave? Who exactly told you you overstayed? There's no exit passport control in the US.

Comment: Was "a man" an officer of the United States government?  What was the date indicated on your passport stamp?

Comment: The us only cares that you leave (specifically they don't care if you go to your own country or somewhere else) so it's when you leave that is important. I guess the most likely cause of this is that you didn't count the day you arrived and the day you left as two separate days that each count as whole days against the 90 day limit.

Comment: @Henrik there are US admission stamp images online where the "until" date falls 91 days after the "admitted" date.  Once a traveler is admitted, counting days is pointless; instead, one should pay attention to the actual "until" date in the passport and in the [online I-94 record](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov).

Comment: My I-94 shows I left on the 90th day and I stayed from June 17th to the 15th of September 2016. I also visited the USA after this these dates with a new ESTA and had no problem.

Comment: @LeeJones: Those dates show you stayed for **91** days, not 90. Remember that both your arrival and departure dates count as one day each.

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/measure/calendar-between.html

Comment: @LeeJones: That calculator is showing you the *difference* between two dates, not the *total number of days* that you would be in the country. On that calculator, if you select a start day of some Saturday, and the end day of the next day (Sunday), then it shows you a difference of 1 day. But if you arrived on Saturday, and left on Sunday, then you would be in the country for two days total. Same for your trip, it shows a difference of 90 days but your total time in the country was 91 days. If you don't believe me, get out a calendar and count the days rather than relying on a calculator app.

Answer (score 2):

The limit on the length of stay under the VWP is 90 days. This is the number of days that you are physically present in the US (any partial days count as whole days). This is based on when you enter and leave the US, the US immigration doesn't care where you come from or where you go after that.

Comment: It's possible to find VWP stamps online where the "until" date is the 91st day after the "admitted" date.  The important thing is not to count days but to compare the date of departure with the "until" date.